# Copy part of the file in the buffer

Tags: search, emacs, copy-paste

I need to copy part of the file (with `re-search-forward`) to another file under the marker. I know how to use `re-search-forward`, but I have problems with buffer.

Am i right with my logic?

- 1) open needed file with temp buffer
- 2) create new buffer
- 3) find needed lines with `re-search-forward` and copy them in this new
  buffer
- 4) insert lines into opened file with `insert-buffer-substring`

Right now i have a function like this:

```el
(defun my-insert-file-name (filename)
  (interactive "*fInsert file name: ")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (when (re-search-forward "#here")
      (forward-line 1)
      (------something should be here-----)))
```

Comment: What about the `copy-to-buffer` function?

Comment: "I have problems with buffer" - What kind of problems are you having? Please [edit] your question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is short on details, but maybe something like this?

```
(let (buf)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (setq buf (current-buffer))
    (insert-file-contents "/file/to/insert")
    (do-stuff-to-temp-buffer)
    (with-current-buffer "buffer-to-insert-into"
      (insert-buffer-substring buf))))
```